# Django class based view not returning current user details

Tags: django, django-views

I am calling the class based view

```
class CurrentUser(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        for user in User.objects.all()
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                fullname = get_full_name(user)
                return Response(fullname)
```

from the url

```
url(r'^currentuser$', views.CurrentUser.as_view(), name='current-user'
```

But it is returning error as follows..

NameError at /currentuser
global name 'get_full_name' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `get_full_name` like this.

```
fullname = user.get_full_name()
```